# Best way to do User Auth on React Native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, api, authentication, native

Im making an app where i've already made the backend using mysql and php, i created an API to store all the data i need, but now im facing a problem on choosing what Auth flow to use.
I've watched some videos, and i have two options: firebase auth, or asyncStorage (with token).

The thing is, i dont really understand if firebase is used when you need a simple authentication flow, because from what i've read firebase does store everything on its own backend, but in my API i need to save that data too. For example, at some point, i will have to link users with one another to rate the jobs that they've done, so im gonna need to hit the API at some point and check whose done a job for who.

That's why i believe i should use the asyncStorage auth flow, and i've watched some videos about it, and they mention a token that supposedly should have each user at the moment they create an account. I havent assigned a random token on my backend to each user, and im not sure what kind of token i should use.
Will i have to change my API too, to use AsyncStorage?

I would appreciate if anyone could link me to a good source on how to use asyncStorage, or something simplier maybe that wont make me change my backend...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood you are trying save some user data once he logins successfully on the app. And this can be done either by using [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) or  [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). You can save/persist the user data in the app with a unique id or token to distinguish him from other users while making an API call.